# Embed a single webforms different fields in to two different pages - Drupal 6

Tags: webforms, forms

In Drupal 6 , I have a webform which asks for basic info like the Name and email. Then on the basis of if the user is a special user (asked with option button) will choose to ask more questions if they are one else will not ask anything else.

I have created 2 webforms to do that. Is there a way to do that with only 1 webform?
More so is it possible to embed the remaining fields in to a different page.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have not received an answer So based on my research I believe the Webform paging can solve this problem since it can display the webform in two parts.